# What' s the meaning of 'mole trap'?

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms, word-usage, slang

sorry if my English is not good .

in season 1-episode 3 of "killing Eve", there a conversation about a murder between Eve and Jin.

Jin want to give something Secretly to Eve.

Eve : What is that?
jin : You might have a little creature yourself.
      Think of this as a friendly, little mole trap.

Comment: It must be the allusion of Agatha Christie's 'The Mousetrap'.

Comment: @siros Might I suggest that a much better place to post this type of question is this forum: https://movies.stackexchange.com They cover Television and Movie questions about meaning and context more than this site.

Answer (score 2):

I must say, I don't know the plot, but I think, '***mole***' is used here in the metaphorical meaning:

: a spy (such as a double agent) who establishes a cover long before beginning espionage

*broadly* : one within an organization who passes on information 
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mole)